# How to group a mixed data set with both numerical values and text data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a data set consisting of numerical values and text data. How to store them together in Matlab? My current approach is to have a numerical value-based matrix and a string array, and put them into a cell array. Is this the standard way to handle this scenario in Matlab?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

yes, this is the way the default value of matrix is 512 character. tho u can increase this limit. use a loop for storing values etc.

Comment: Yes bit-question, a cell array is a good way to handle data of mixed types. As for umar mention of character array default size, I am not aware of such a thing in Matlab (maybe you could provide a reference to this). Finally, depending on your data set and your particular conditions you can use a loop to store your data in your cell array but it is often possible (and preferable) to do it without a loop.